# What does the output of the monmlp.fit (MLP package) in R represent?

Tags: r, machine-learning

r <- monmlp.fit(x, y, hidden1 =5, hidden2 = 0, iter.max = 500, Th = logistic, To = linear, monotone = NULL)

I am getting the following output. How do I interpret this?

** Ensemble 1 
1 0.1228054 
** 0.1228054

If I have 5 nodes in the hidden layer, should I be expecting 5 weights somewhere?

Comment: Possible duplicate: < http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16228954/how-to-use-mlp-multilayer-perceptron-in-r >.

Comment: I checked that post. Was not able to figure it out.